# Default FTP username, Password in PHP

Tags: php, apache, drupal, ubuntu, ftp

Drupal asking for ftp access while installing module. I found that PHP ftp extension is installed in my server. But whats its default username and password or How to add ftp users ? I am using Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP FTP extension is FTP client, not server. You have to provide your FTP account to Drupal (the account that has write permission you use to upload your files)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Yes You are right, Its FTP Client extension .So should I install ftp server separately along with Apache ? If not from where i will get the default ftp username password. I have installed Lampp.